# WP_Query returns random IDs on taxonomy queries with posts_per_page argument

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get latest product IDs from specific WooCommerce category. For some reason on every page load I get different product IDs and not the latest ones.

Here is the WP_Query arguments:

```
array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'a-product-category' 
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
)
```

This generates following SQL query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (
    wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
)
WHERE 1=1
AND (
    wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (259,260,262)
)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND (
    wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Like I said, returned post ids are always somewhat different (they are from correct category though). What I understand is that the correct behaviour for this query is that it should return five latest post from the specified category.

I executed the query directly on SQL-server to rule out any WordPress or plugin issues and still got random post ids.

If I remove the tax_query (removes wp_term_relationship related SQL commands) or set posts_per_page to -1 (removes LIMIT 0, 5) the post ids seems to be in correct order.

However, this works as I think it should work on my development server. This happens on the production server (which uses WPengine as hosting provider and MySQL 5.6.32).

Any advice is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was due the fact if you try to do `ORDER BY` with non-unique data, the results may vary from what is expected, especially in a clustered MySQL environment *(which I think WPengine uses)*. In this case the `post_date` was same along multiple posts because I used an importer to create them.

The same thing happened when I tried to sort products by price and some products had the same prices.

To solve this problem in WP_Query I used a fallback to the `order_by` argument:

```php
'order_by' => 'date ID'
```

Which translates to the SQL query:

```sql
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC, wp_posts.ID ASC
```

More information about this issue can be found here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69732